# Google OR-Tools: Using in an IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, or-tools

I have the Problem that i want to add OR-Tools into my project via eclipse IDE. I want to use the Linear Solver. I added the two jars form the downloaded Zip file. Now i want to run the SimpleLpExample from the OR-Tools site. I've got the Error that no jniortools in java.library.path. I see that at other posts they say you have to run make third_party and make java, but i don't know where i have to run these commands.

When somebody added it successfully into an IDE it would be glade when this person can explain how he does it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to add the path to the jniortools shared library I'm eclipse.
All dynamic libraries are located in the lib/ directory of the extracted archive.

To add the correct path, please follow these [instructions](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/):

Comment: How i can add it to jniortools shared library path ? I can not find shared library jniortools. I can only find a jniortool.so file at my lib folder.